# How to use Backup-SqlDatabase with SAS token?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to implement log shipping using `Backup-sqldatabase` command, but `SqlCredential` is a required parameter for Azure Storage uploads according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/backup-sqldatabase?view=sqlserver-ps). However, I'm using a Shared Access Token credential, so I can't really use the `SqlCredential` parameter. If I do, this is the error I get:

> Backup-SqlDatabase : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Use of WITH CREDENTIAL syntax is not valid for credentials containing a Shared Access Signature.

Does this mean that SAS tokens/credential can't be used for `Backup-sqldatabase`?

If I don't include the `SqlCredential` parameter, I get this error:

> Backup-SqlDatabase : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The file name
> "https://xxxxdev.blob.core.windows.net/DESKTOP-MCxxxx-MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER-Test123-132767637897201085.bak" is invalid as a backup device name for the specified device type. Reissue the BACKUP statement with a valid file name and device type.

Test123 is just a random test database I created on localhost for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like SAS token is not supported for `Backup-sqldatabase` at this time.

The workaround is creating a Maintenance Plan, but that means T-SQL backups no PowerShell.

In [this article](https://www.sqlshack.com/backup-sql-databases-to-azure-using-the-database-maintenance-plan/), you can learn how we can fix the ‘WITH CREDENTIAL syntax is not valid for credentials containing a Shared Access Signature’ error and learn to back up the SQL database to Azure Blob storage using the SQL Server maintenance plan.